# Azure Easy Tables init(?) fails on one portion of app but succeeds on another. What's happening?

Tags: android, azure, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on a Xamarin.Android app. I'm connecting to an Azure Mobile App and I'm getting/storing data in an EasyTable.

Now here's my code for the user 'login' and registration. This are just test queries so don't mind the obviously unsecure login:

```
public async Task Initialize()
        {
            MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(myappwebsiteinazurestring);

            string path = Path.Combine(MobileServiceClient.DefaultDatabasePath, "UserSync.db");
            var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
            store.DefineTable<Users_Table>();
            await MobileService.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store, new MobileServiceSyncHandler());
            userTable = MobileService.GetSyncTable<Users_Table>();
        }

        public async Task SyncUsers()
        {
            await userTable.PullAsync("Users_Table", userTable.CreateQuery());
            await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
        }

        public async Task<List<Users_Table>> loginUser(string username, string password)
        {
            List<Users_Table> userLogin = await userTable
                .Where(user => user.Username == username && user.Password == password)
                .ToListAsync();
            await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            return userLogin;
        }
```

That's for the login and initialization. Now here is the register part:

```
 public async Task AddUser(Users_Table user)
        {
            var InsUser = new Users_Table
            {
                Name = user.Name,
                Username = user.Username,
                Password = user.Password,
                LicensePlate = user.LicensePlate,
                Email = user.Email,
                Exp = user.Exp
            };

            await userTable.InsertAsync(InsUser);
            await SyncUsers();

        }
```

Now that's fine and all. Here's how I call them from my app:

```
 private async void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            EditText username = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.LoginEditTextUsername);
            EditText password = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.LoginEditTextPassword);

            var prog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            prog.SetMessage("Logging in...");
            prog.Show();
            AzureDataService az = new AzureDataService();
            List<Users_Table> user = new List<Users_Table>();

            try
            {
                await az.Initialize();
                user = await az.loginUser(username.Text, password.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, "Error: " + ex.Message + "\n" + ex.Source, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                return;
            }
```

And the registration:

```
 private async void CreateProfile()
        {
            EditText regUsername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.RegisterLayoutUsername);
            EditText regPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.RegisterLayoutPassword);
            EditText regConfirmPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.RegisterLayoutConfirmPassword);
            EditText regPlateNumber = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.RegisterLayoutPlateNumber);
            EditText regEmail = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.RegisterLayoutEmail);
            EditText regName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.RegisterLayoutName);

            var user = new Users_Table
            {
                Username = regUsername.Text,
                Password = regPassword.Text,
                LicensePlate = parseLicensePlate(regPlateNumber.Text),
                Name = regName.Text,
                Email = regEmail.Text,
                Exp = 0
            };

            try
            {
                var pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pd.SetMessage("Creating Profile...");
                pd.Show();
                AzureDataService az = new AzureDataService();
                await az.Initialize();
                await az.AddUser(user);
                pd.Dismiss();
            }
```

Once I test this on any device with the apk, the login fails. The app receives a null Users_Table and therefore shows the username/password incorrect message.

The weird thing however is this: the register goes through with no problems. And once I successfully register a new user, the login also goes through, for existing users and the newly created one. It's like something happens in the register method that kickstarts the connection to whatever.

Has anybody experienced this? What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by adding the syncusers() before any processes, making the login for example like so:

```
    public async Task<List<Users_Table>> loginUser(string username, string password)
    {



        await SyncUsers();//here
        List<Users_Table> userLogin = await userTable
            .Where(user => user.Username == username && user.Password == password)
            .ToListAsync();
        await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
        return userLogin;
    }
```